# How to create a Windows Bootable USB?

Tags: usb-creator

How to make a bootable USB. I am using UBUNTU 13.04 LTS and want to make a bootable usb to install windows

Suggest any Ubuntu based usb creators to make a bootable Windows Flash drive.

Answer (score -1):

I did this when my windows 8 was wiped.  Just go to the store and serch unetbootin.  Download it and find ur iso to burn onto the usb.  if u have any questions just ask.
thx